# Invariant lattices of group representations over a $p$-adic field

Tags: nt.number-theory, gr.group-theory, rt.representation-theory

Let $G$ be a finite group, $K$ be a $p$-adic field with an uniformizer $\pi$ and residue field $k \cong \Bbb F_q$, and $V$ be an irreducible representation of $G$ over $K$.

Let $X_{V}^G$ be the set of $G$-invariant lattices in $V$ modulo scaling (if $\Lambda$ is invariant so is $a \Lambda$ for any $a \in K^{\times}$).

For any $\Lambda \in X_V^G$, by reduction we get a $k$-representation $\rho_{\Lambda}$ of $G$ (well-defined up to isomorphism). Let $Y_{V}$ be the set of all isomorphism classes of such representations respect to $V$.

It's well-known that $X_V^G \not = \varnothing$ and $\rho_{\Lambda}^{ss}$ (semisimplification) is independent of $\Lambda$. My question is,

- How do we compute $\# X^G_V$ and $\# Y_V$?
- How do we classify the shape of $X_{V}^G$ (a little vague, maybe inside Bruhat-Tits building as below)?

If $\text{dim}V=2$, then we can consider the relation $\pi L_1\subseteq L_1 \subseteq L_2$ to make $X_V$ the set of all lattices module scaling in $V$ a tree i.e the Bruhat-Tits tree. Using such tool, one proves that $X_V^G$ is a finite set (convex inside $X_V$) and is a singleton, or a segment, or a graph that all neighbors of any interior point in $X_{V}$ lie in $X_{V}^G$.

And the reduction representations behaves differently according the shape of $X_V^G$ and their positions, in particular we can use one reduction representation to detect the shape of all reduction representations. From this we can construct some reduction representations (reducible but not semi-simple), which is probably due to Ribet in his proof of the converse to Herbrand theorem (However, the generalized Ribet lemma follows a different approach).

Example: $G=S_3$, $V$ the unique $2$-dim irreducible representation over $\Bbb Q_p$, if $p \not= 3$ then the invariant lattice is unique. If $p=3$ there are only two invariant lattices $\mathbb Z_p^2$ and $\Bbb Z_p(1,1)+\Bbb Z_p(3,0) $, and the two mod $p$ representations are reducible and not isomorphic (the semisimplification is $\text{trivial} \oplus \text{sgn}$).

What if the dimension is large than 2? $X^G_V$ is still a finite set by a compactness argument. Moreover, the global field analogue (assuming absolute irreducibility)is still true by local-global principle for lattices. This can be also seen from Jordan–Zassenhaus theorem.

Example: If some $\rho_{\Lambda_0}$ is irreducible, then it's not hard to see $X_V^G=\{ \Lambda_0 \}$: irreducibility means there is no invariant lattice between $\pi \Lambda_0$ and $\Lambda_0$, so if there is other any invariant lattice $\Lambda$, we can assume $\Lambda \subseteq \Lambda_0$ by scaling, then consider $\pi \Lambda_0+\Lambda$ to get $\Lambda \subseteq \pi \Lambda_0$, replacing $\Lambda$ by $\pi^{-1}\Lambda$ eventually we get a contradiction.  , $S_n$ act on the $\mathbb Q_p$ vector space $V=\{(x_i) \in \Bbb Q_p^n |\sum_{i=1}^n x_i=0\}$ by permuting the coordinates. How do we compute all invariant lattices?

Example: let $S_n$ act on the $\mathbb Q_p$ vector space $V=\{(x_i) \in \Bbb Q_p^n |\sum_{i=1}^n x_i=0\}$ by permuting the coordinates. Then we can compute all invariant lattices--precisely those lying between the natural two lattices i.e $\mathbb Z^n$ and its dual, see *Feit, Walter. Integral representations of Weyl groups rationally equivalent to the reflection representation, J. Group Theory 1, 1998, no. 3, 213–218.*

Edit: I thought about the problem for a while and some original problems are solved. To my limited knowledge, not many examples are known. For example what about $S_5$? I don't know how to compute all invariant lattices of the irreducible 5-dimensional representations and the 6-dimensional representation.

Comment: I don't know how much modular representation theory and integral representation theory you know. I know that I know too little to give a complete answer. Listing all $k[G]$-modules obtained from $V$ is not that hard. Take one $\Lambda$ and look at the composition series. magma has a command SubmoduleLattice. That ends up listing you all $\mathcal{O}[G]$-lattices between $\Lambda$ and $\pi\Lambda$.

Comment: https://mathoverflow.net/questions/32311/explicit-integral-representation-theory also asks about related question. The references I know are Curtis-Reiner's Methods of Representation Theory, Reiner's survey Integral representation theory and Reiner's Maximal orders.

Comment: @ChrisWuthrich Thank you! I read some of them, but it's not obvious to me that one can scal any lattice to make sure it lies between $\Lambda_0$ and $\pi \Lambda_0$. And the irreducibility assumption is necessary to make sure that there are only finitely many of them (up to scaling).

Comment: For $S_n$ the question mentioned above points at a book by James and Kerber...

Comment: no, not all $G$-lattices will contain $\pi \Lambda$. There are only finitely many $\mathcal{O}[G]$-lattices of a given rank; that is a consequence of Jordan-Zassenhaus and does not need the irreducibility of $V$. But if $V$ is not irreducible, you will face extension problems on top.

Comment: @ChrisWuthrich Thank you again! To my knowledge, the representation I mention for $S_n$ is very special—it induced by the action of Weyl group on the root system, so there is an invariant inner product and it's the main tool to compute all invariant lattices.... I don't know other cases, let me check the book you mentioned...

Comment: @ChrisWuthrich No, irreducibility is necessary as I am considering the sublattices rather than isomorphism classes of $O[G]$ modules.. There are some twists I don't mention in the question to get the result. The compactness arguments is another proof, and it relies on Nakayama lemma. For example, if $V=V_1\oplus V_2$, then  $\Lambda_1 \oplus a\Lambda_2  (a \in K)$ gives infinitely many invariant lattices.

Comment: I meant isomorphism classes indeed.

Comment: @ChrisWuthrich I am more interested in invariant sublattices, thank you anyway.

Comment: For irreducible $V$ it is the same thing, though, by Schur.

Comment: Only recently came across this question. Answers to some of these questions have been given in two recent works by Junecue Suh: https://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/abs/pii/S0021869321000892 and https://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/abs/pii/S0021869321005019