# $\mathbb{Z}$-forms of rational representation of finite group

Tags: rt.representation-theory, finite-groups

Let $G$ be a finite group and let $\rho\colon G\to \mathrm{GL}_n(\mathbb{Q})$ be a representation of $G$.

How does one go about classifying the $\mathbb{Z}$-forms of $\rho$?

For example: [here](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/32311/explicit-integral-representation-theory) it is claimed that the $2$-dimensional representation of $\mathrm{Sym}(3)$ has $2$ distinct $\mathbb{Z}$-forms --- how is this proven?  What happens for the standard representation of $\mathrm{Sym}(4)$?

Comment: For 2-dimensional things are particularly simple because one easily understands finite subgroups of $\mathrm{GL}_2(\mathbf{Z})$ up to conjugation.

Comment: You can distinguish the two $\mathbb{Z}$-forms by reducing mod $3$ and looking for fixed points.

Comment: @DaveBenson thanks! Does something similar happen for Sym(4)?  What about Sym(n)?  I guess classifying Z-forms is less procedural and more ad-hoc?

Answer (score 6):

I recommend looking at Chapters 3 and 4 of the new Curtis and Reiner, "Methods of Representation Theory I" (...when I say new, I mean 1981! Am I showing my age?) as well as Reiner's "Maximal Orders" (1974). The subject is subtle, but there are some good results.